# Crear proyecto con ASP.NET en Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, iis

Estoy intentando crear un proyecto de ASP.NET con Visual Studio 2012. Tengo Windows 7 Professional.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que a la hora de crear el proyecto, me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado mil soluciones y ninguna termina con el fallo.

-Ya he activado todas estas casillas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Ya he ejecutado mil veces el archivo aspnet_regiis.exe tanto de la ruta C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 como el de la ruta C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

-Y por mas que abro el Administrador de IIS, al hacer click en "Cambiar la verison de .NET Framework" me sigue apareciendo la v2.0.50727 (aunque la cambie a la v4)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco infinitamente a quien me eche una mano.

Un saludo y gracias!!